.Net Core MVC: how to get partial view name in razor
.Net Core MVC.
In all my views and partial views, I use this line to get its path (url)
<span>@(this.ViewContext.View as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView).Path;</span>

(and also some other lines to get the models name in case its strongly-typed and some other info)
Now, to avoid having to add this code in every view or partial, I have tried to create a partial (_debugPartial.cshtml) with these lines, and then including it in every other view/partial with
<partial name="_DebugInfoPartial" />

But this does not work: I always get the name of this new partial, ("/Views/Shared/_debugPartialchstml") instead of tha path of the view/partial that is including it...
How could this be achieved?

You could use the custom tag helper to achieve your requirement. The partial view is also a view , which will always use the same view path.
More detail about how to use it, you could refer to below codes:
Create a custom taghelper:
[HtmlTargetElement("debuginfo")]
public class DebugInfoTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var viewPath = (ViewContext.View as RazorView)?.Path;
        // Capture any other information you need

        output.TagName = "span";
        output.Content.SetContent($"View Path: {viewPath}");
        // Render other debug information as needed
    }
}

Import it inside the _ViewImports.cshtml.
@using WebApplication1
@namespace WebApplication1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, {yourapplicationnamespace}
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Usage:
<debuginfo></debuginfo>

Result:



Any idea how could I get model's name inside tag helper?
